# Counting list variables with dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to make a program that can count the number of fruits in a given list.

I've tried a `for` loop but didn't have any success. I have also tried a `Counter` but that would remove the second `'banana'` and only recognizes one.

```
c = { 'banana': 'fruit', 'apple': 'fruit', 'pizza': 'fastfood', 'fries': 'fastfood' }
v = [ 'fries', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'pizza' ]

r = len([v for v in c if c.items() == 'fruit' in c.value()])

print(r)
```

I expected that this would give me the number of fruits but instead, I have an output of `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a set from all fruits and use that:

```
c = { 'banana': 'fruit', 'apple': 'fruit', 'pizza': 'fastfood', 'fries': 'fastfood' }

# collect all fruits into a set that only contains fruit
fixed = set(k for k,v in c.items() if v=="fruit")  # cheating by creating the set in setup ;)

v = [ 'fries', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'pizza' ]

r = sum(f in fixed for f in v)

print(r)
```

Returns 3 -  because `True` ( the result of the O(1) set lookup) equals to 1 and `False` equals 0.

---

This solution is worse then [Daniel Trugman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54186129/7505395) under most conditions, in other conditions it is slightly faster:

- to create the set it accesses each *value* of the dict once to build the set - after that it is using the created set to decide if something is a fruit:

Consider:

```
c = {'banana':'fruit'}
v = ['banana' * 100000]
fixed = set(k for k,v in c.items() if v=="fruit")
```

The dict-comprehension directly has to acces the *value* of `c['banana']` 100000 times and do 100000 `c[val] == 'fruit'` to check if it is a fruit. This is slower than checking 100000 times `'banana' in fixed` on the constructed set.

For the example at hand the dict comp is fine.

---

Most of the time the dict-comp is faster:

```
setup_code = """
c = { 'banana': 'fruit', 'apple': 'fruit', 'pizza': 'fastfood', 'fries': 'fastfood' }
v = [ 'fries', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'pizza' ]
fixed = set(k for k,v in c.items() if v=="fruit")
"""

setup_code2 = """
c = { 'banana': 'fruit', 'apple': 'fruit', 'pizza': 'fastfood', 'fries': 'fastfood' }
v = ['banana']*1000  
fixed = set(k for k,v in c.items() if v=="fruit")
"""

using_set = """
# collect all fruits into a set that only contains fruit

r = sum(1 if f in fixed else 0 for f in v)
"""

using_dict_comp = """
r = sum(1 for val in v if c[val] == 'fruit')
"""

import timeit

print("set:", timeit.timeit(using_set,setup=setup_code,number=10000))
print("dict:", timeit.timeit(using_dict_comp,setup=setup_code,number=1000))
print("set:", timeit.timeit(using_set,setup=setup_code2,number=10000))
print("dict:", timeit.timeit(using_dict_comp,setup=setup_code2,number=10000))
```

Output:

```
'set:', 0.0069959163665771484 
'dict:', 0.0006661415100097656

'set:', 0.6653687953948975  # this "fasteness" goes away as soon as more items are in the set
'dict:', 0.7533159255981445
```

Comment: Lookup in a dict is faster than lookup in a set. So your solution seems to be less-efficient than the original one.

Comment: @DanielTrugman by collecting only keys into the set that are `fruit` the lookup does not need to evaluate the dictionaries _values_ - each item in the dict is touched once, the setlookup is O(1) - if you use the dict you need to access the "banana": "fruit" twice. Why do you think that set-lookup is slower then dict-lookup? the dict.keys() _is_ a set().

Comment: As far as I know, dict access is implemented using a hashmap, whereas set is implemented using a balanced tree. The first is O(1), the second is O(logn). For these data-sets, this is nonsense, but for larger sets, this becomes relevant. The fact that dict.keys() returns a set is is only a convenient way to represent the collection of all keys in a dict, it has nothing to do with the underlying implementation.

Comment: @ DanielTrugman yeah you are correct -yours is more performant - added measurements

Comment: @PatrickArtner, I would first like to say I enjoyed this thread thanks to you :) Second, since you were right, and the slow part is accessing the value, I improved my implementation for performance-oriented programmers like yourself! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Just try:

```
r = sum(1 for val in v if c[val] == 'fruit')
```

Or, like @jpp suggested (a bit shorter):

```
r = sum(c[val] == 'fruit' for val in v)
```

Or, if you need speed, like @Patrick Artner:

```
ctag = { k: v for k, v in c.items() if v == 'fruit' }
r = sum(1 for val in v if val in ctag)
```

**Explanation:** Accessing the value and comparing each time is quite expensive. It is cheaper to create a new dictionary where all keys are fruits, and then simply ignore the values. This is better than using a set, because sets are implemented using balanced trees with search complexity of O(logN) whereas dicts are implemented using hashmaps with search complexity of O(1) as long as the number of the items in the map doesn't exceed the inner capacity by much...

Answer (score 0):

Try this first figure out type then find occurrences of keys of dictonary c

`c = { 'banana': 'fruit', 'apple': 'fruit', 'pizza': 'fastfood', 'fries':'fastfood' }`

`v = [ 'fries', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'pizza' ]`

`result = [c[i] for i in v] #this will iterate and give the type of element`

`output={}`

`for key in c.values():
         output[key] =str(result.count(key))`

`print(output)`

Comment: How come this gives 5 outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
res = sum(c[value] == 'fruit' for value in v)
```

This works because `bool` is treated as a subclass of `int`, i.e. Boolean `True` / `False` are equivalent to integers `1` / `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Something short (similar to @Daniel Trugman's answer but slightly simpler):

```
r = sum(1 for value in c.values() if value == 'fruit')
```